# HTTP FAILED: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream exception while making https request

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

We are previously using http apis and now we have migrated to https, with same code we are facing the exception HTTP FAILED: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream (this is for some device and for some network calls). We are using the 
    OkHttp and Retrofit from android app. Below is our code

````
@Provides
    @ApplicationScope
    OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClientV2(
            HttpLoggingInterceptor logging,
            Interceptor headerInterceptor) {
    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    //Removed custom timeout units
    return builder.addInterceptor(headerInterceptor)
            .addInterceptor(logging)
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
            .readTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

 }

@Provides
@ApplicationScope
Interceptor provideRetrofitHeaderV2(final SharedPreferencesUtil sharedPreferencesUtil) {
    return new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request original = chain.request();

            Request.Builder builder = original.newBuilder();
            builder.header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .method(original.method(), original.body());
            if (sharedPreferencesUtil != null) {
                if (sharedPreferencesUtil.isLogin()) {

                    String loginToken = sharedPreferencesUtil.getLoginToken();
                    builder.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + loginToken);
                }
            }

            builder.addHeader("Connection", "close");

            Request request = builder.build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    };
}

@Provides
@ApplicationScope
HttpLoggingInterceptor provideLoggingInterceptorV2() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    } else {
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE);
    }
    return logging;
}

@Provides
@ApplicationScope
Retrofit provideRetrofitV2(OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
    return new Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();
}```
````

Things we have already tried:

- Add header with `addHeader("Connection", "close")`
- Add connection pool to limit the ideal connections
- increase the timeout time

Any help will be appreciated, we are facing this issue for quite some time now.

Comment: Seems like an OkHttp Issue  https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2738

Comment: Already checked that most of the answers are not working with our case.

Comment: @Asheesh I run with real device and everything will be ok.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this happen and figured out a workaround. This was caused by the use of the HttpLoggingInterceptor. Through debugging into the okhttp code I found that it was throwing that error because the length of the body did not match what the content length header in the response was. If it receives a content header it uses a FixedLengthSource and that will throw the "unexpected end of stream" error when it is read. You can see this in the source https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/okhttp_3.9.x/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/internal/http1/Http1Codec.java  openResponseBody method

As a workaround I added a **response** interpreter to my builder that strips out the content-length header which causes it to use an UnknownLengthSource.

```
 private static final Interceptor REWRITE_CONTENT_LENGTH_INTERCEPTOR = new Interceptor() {
    @Override public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
      Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());
      return originalResponse.newBuilder().removeHeader("Content-Length")
              .build();
    }
  };
```