# SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x74d2dc46c8: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

In retrofit I am sending XML in request and in response server will send XML in response. I am using proxy to consume that API. But I am always getting - HTTP FAILED: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on null. I have tried solutions mentioned in stackoverflow but nothing worked. Below code is for retrofit client -

```
    fun getRetrofitClient(context: Context): RestAPI {

    if (mRetrofitClient == null) {

        val cf: CertificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
        val cert: InputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mycert)
        val ca: Certificate
        ca = try {
            cf.generateCertificate(cert)
        } finally {
            cert.close()
        }

         val keyStoreType: String = KeyStore.getDefaultType()
        val keyStore: KeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType)
        keyStore.load(null, null)
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca)
        val proxy = Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, InetSocketAddress("xxxx.xx.xx.xx",xxxx ))
        val tmfAlgorithm: String = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()
        val tmf: TrustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm)
        tmf.init(keyStore)

        val sslContext: SSLContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2")
        sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null)

        val spec = ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
            .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
            .cipherSuites(
                CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
            CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
            CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
            CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
            CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
            )
            .build()


        val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .followRedirects(true)
        .followSslRedirects(true)
        .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .sslSocketFactory(socketFactory)
        .socketFactory(socketFactory)
        .hostnameVerifier(getHostnameVerifier())
        .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
        .proxy(proxy)
        .connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec))



        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/xx/")
            .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient.build())
            .build()
        mRetrofitClient = retrofit.create(RestAPI::class.java!!)
    }
    return mRetrofitClient!!
}

fun getHostnameVerifier(): HostnameVerifier? {
    return object : HostnameVerifier {
        override fun verify(hostname: String?, session: SSLSession?): Boolean {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Below code is for Rest API -

```
interface RestAPI {
    @Headers("Content-Type: text/xml","Connection: keep-alive","Transfer-Encoding: chunked","Cache-Control: no-cache","Accept: */*","Host: xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx","Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br")
    @POST("BillQuery/V1.0")
    abstract fun billQuery(@Body input:String): Call<String>
}
```

I tried volley also, same issue. But it's working fine in Postman. I have added header like postman. Still it doesn't work.

Please help.

Comment: does it work without proxy?

Comment: I can't access that API from my country without proxy.

Answer (score 1):

`unexpected end of stream` can be thrown by okhttp if the Response-Headers cannot be parsed or if the length in the Response-Header  `Content-Length` doesn't match with the actual length of the response body (see [HTTP FAILED: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream exception while making https request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55473516/http-failed-java-io-ioexception-unexpected-end-of-stream-exception-while-makin?rq=1)).

In your case, okhttp wants to send a unencrypted connect to the HTTP-proxy and fails at this step to parse the Reponse-Headers from the proxy-response i guess. The proxy gives okhttp an invalid answer. Could you try with postman to connect to the proxy through HTTP?

Comment: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: limit=0 content=…

Comment: Does the response from the proxy contains any Headers? This error indicates, that there no Headers returned by the proxy.

Comment: there is no headers return from proxy.

Comment: This is the problem. OkHttp fails, because it's expected the proxy to return some Headers.